# Fix table body when screen resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a table with  fixed header and first column like the example belows:

```js
(function() {
  var demo, fixedTable;
  fixedTable = function(el) {
    var $body, $header, $sidebar;
    $body = $(el).find('.fixedTable-body');
    $sidebar = $(el).find('.fixedTable-sidebar table');
    $header = $(el).find('.fixedTable-header table');
    return $($body).scroll(function() {
      $($sidebar).css('margin-top', -$($body).scrollTop());
      return $($header).css('margin-left', -$($body).scrollLeft());
    });
  };
  demo = new fixedTable($('#demo'));
}.call(this));
```

```css
.fixedTable .table {
  background-color: white;
  width: auto;
}

.fixedTable .table tr td,
.fixedTable .table tr th {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fixedTable-header {
  width: 510px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.fixedTable-sidebar {
  width: 110px;
  height: 310px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.fixedTable-body {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 510px;
  height: 310px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixedTable" id="demo">
  <header class="fixedTable-header">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
          <th>D</th>
          <th>E</th>
          <th>F</th>
          <th>G</th>
          <th>H</th>
          <th>I</th>
          <th>J</th>
          <th>K</th>
          <th>L</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </header>
  <aside class="fixedTable-sidebar">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>14567567465447567467</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </aside>
  <div class="fixedTable-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I do a screen resize the body of the table (div class="fixedTable-body") gets beyond the table.

Could anyone suggest a solution to fix the body ?

This is the link for codepen: http://codepen.io/ajkochanowicz/pen/KHdih

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by setting the width of the body like this

```
.fixedTable-body {
  overflow: auto;
  width: calc(96% - 200px);
  height: 450px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a media query and set the properties like

```
codepen.io/junaid_jedi/pen/yVwQzj?editors=1100
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but now there's two scrollbars on the screen and on the table. Is there a way to hide the scrollbars on the screen?